# How do I get the dynamic grid view android?

Tags: android, android-gridview

My activity:

```
  package com.app.redbuslayout;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    GridView grid;
    RelativeLayout r1;
    String maxrows;
    int maxcol;
    int[] imageId = {
              R.drawable.seat,
              R.drawable.seat,
              R.drawable.seat,
              R.drawable.seat,
              R.drawable.seat,
              R.drawable.seat,
              R.drawable.seat,
              R.drawable.seat ,R.drawable.seat,
              R.drawable.seat,
              R.drawable.seat,
              R.drawable.seat,
              R.drawable.seat,
              R.drawable.seat,
              R.drawable.seat,
              R.drawable.seat,
              R.drawable.seat,
              R.drawable.seat,
              R.drawable.seat,

              R.drawable.seat,
              };

              @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

           CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(MainActivity.this, imageId);
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);

        // define the RelativeLayout layout parameters.
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

         grid =new GridView(MainActivity.this);

         grid.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
         grid.setNumColumns(maxcol);



         grid.setAdapter(adapter);
         relativeLayout.addView(grid);

            // set the RelativeLayout as our content view
            setContentView(relativeLayout, relativeLayoutParams);

        new GetRoute().execute("http://sb2.reloadit.in/TravelServices.asmx/Getlayout");
    }

     private     class GetRoute extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {
            /*String mJourneyDate;
            public GetData(String pJourneyDate) {
                this.mJourneyDate = pJourneyDate;
            }*/ProgressDialog pd = null;
                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();

                    pd = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Loading...", true);
                }

                @Override
                protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
                    String response;

                    try {
                        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
                        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                         nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("RouteScheduleID","428205707"));

                         nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("JourneyDate","2014-12-16"));


                         httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
                        HttpResponse responce = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                        HttpEntity httpEntity = responce.getEntity();

                        response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
                        Log.d("response is", response);

                        return new JSONObject(response);

                    } catch (Exception ex) {

                        ex.printStackTrace();

                    }

                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) 
                {
                    super.onPostExecute(result);
                    //Log.v("TAG_RESULTadapter",""+result);

                    pd.dismiss();
                    if(result != null)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            JSONObject jobj = result.getJSONObject("Response");
                            String message = jobj.getString("Message");
                            String issuceess = jobj.getString("IsSuccess");

                            if(issuceess.equals("true"))
                            {

                                JSONObject layout = result.getJSONObject("Layout");  
                                // Log.v("TAG_routearray",""+layoutarray);
                                  maxrows=layout.getString("MaxRows");
                                  maxcol=layout.getInt("MaxColumns");
                                /* Log.v("TAG_maxrows",""+maxrows);
                                    Log.v("TAG_Maxcol",""+maxcol);*/
                                    JSONArray routearray = layout.getJSONArray("SeatDetails");
                                    for (int i = 0; i < routearray.length(); i++) {

                                     String Row = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Row");
                                 // Log.v("TAG_routearray",""+Row);
                                     String Col = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Col");
                                     String Height = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Height");
                                  String  Width = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Width");
                                     String SeatNo = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("SeatNo");
                                  String Gender = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Gender");

                                         String Deck = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Deck");
                                         String IsAvailable = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("IsAvailable");
                                      String  Fare = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Fare");
                                     Log.v("TAG_Maxfare",""+Fare);

                                    }

                            }
                        }


                        catch (Exception e) 
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Network Problem", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
}
}
```

Adapter class:

```
          package com.app.redbuslayout;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomGrid extends BaseAdapter{
    private Context mContext;

    private final int[] Imageid;
      public CustomGrid(Context c,int[] Imageid ) {
          mContext = c;
          this.Imageid = Imageid;

      }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return Imageid.length;
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return null;
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      View grid;
      LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
          if (convertView == null) {
            grid = new View(mContext);
        grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_grid, null);

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);

            imageView.setImageResource(Imageid[position]);
          } else {
            grid = (View) convertView;
          }



      return grid;
    }
}
```

In my application from json I got maxrows and maxcolumns. Based on the maxrow and maxcolumn  I want to create grid view with same number of columns and rows. Every grid contains same image.

So how do I create this gridview dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

```
LazyAdapter adapter;

adapter = new LazyAdapter(this, Col , Height , Width, SeatNo );
        grid.setAdapter((ListAdapter) adapter);
```

and in LazyAdapter extends with BaseAdapter class

```
public LazyAdapter(Activity a, String[] d, String[] textname,
            String catID, String subCatIDD) {
        activity = a;
        data = d;
        textdataamag = textname;
        this.catID = catID;
        this.subCatIDD = subCatIDD;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }
```

it is constructor to hold the view that you send from gridview class.

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
//here you get handle your view
```

ex.

```
View vi = convertView;
        if (convertView == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.masterindex, null);

        TextView text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.channelTXT);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.channelIMG);

        }

return view
```

to handle LazyAdapter  class you may take full reference from
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/08/android-custom-grid-view-example-with-image-and-text.html
CustomGridViewAdapter.java class

Comment: thank you for your reply. but it is not working. i want to set rows and cols dynamically based on json data. The image in every row and col is same

Comment: i edited my code suman. now tell me  how i set the maxcols to setNumColumn()

Comment: in order to make your gridview dynamic i am sending variable to LazyAdapter

Comment: grid.setNumColumns(Col);

Comment: ha suman i tried this. but it is not working. if col value is 5. but it shows only one col